# Google sheets script - export to PDF as fit to page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scale, urlfetch, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to get my script to export a google sheet to a PDF while keeping it formatted to a single sheet (a one page invoice). Fit to width works, but I need it to either scale to page or fit to height, otherwise it will continue on to the next page. Since there are variables in input data, simply widening the columns doesn't necessarily work or look good.

I've tried both `&fith=true` and `&scale=4`. Fit to height doesn't do anything at all, which is weird, and scale 4 correctly scales my second sheet (which is the one I want) but also sends my first sheet, which is just my data capture before formatting. I have a `gid#` listed for my second sheet, so I have no idea why the scale command sends both sheets.

This is the script as I currently have it:

```
const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=letter' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=1472610169'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
```

What this does well is that it exports the correct sheet only, and it's fit to width, however with certain amounts of input characters, it extends to a second page, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
+ '&scale=4'              // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page
+ '&fith=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page height, false for actual size
```

Instead of fitw